# Wxpython browse for or drag and drop folder

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, wxpython

I currently have this code below to manualy get a directory path, I would like to add drag and drop as well, so I could drag and drop the folder into the window.

```
self.pathindir1 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel1, -1, pos=(35, 120), size=(300, 25))
self.buttonout = wx.Button(self.panel1, -1, "Open", pos=(350,118))
self.buttonout.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.openindir1)

def openindir1(self, event):
    global indir1
    dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, "Choose a directory:", style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE | wx.DD_NEW_DIR_BUTTON)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        indir1 = dlg.GetPath()
        self.SetStatusText("Your selected directory is: %s" % indir1)
    self.pathindir1.Clear()
    self.pathindir1.WriteText(indir1)
```

Comment: I think drag and drop already supported by wx.DirDialog, but this operation means "Copy and Paste". Maybe you need to implement your own DirDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you  want to combine a `wx.DirDialog` with a drag-and-drop entry, as they are two different ways of reading a file path inside your program.
For a drag-and-drop entry you may want to define a `wx.FileDropTarget` class:

```
class MyFileDropTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):
    """"""
    def __init__(self, window):
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.window = window

    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
        self.window.notify(filenames)
#
```

Then in your Frame:

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        ...........................
        dt1 = MyFileDropTarget(self)
        self.tc_files = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.tc_files.SetDropTarget(dt1)
        ...........................

    def notify(self, files):
        """Update file in testcontrol after drag and drop"""
        self.tc_files.SetValue(files[0])
```

With this example you generate a Text Control where you can drop your file.
Note that what the notify method receives in its `files` parameter is a list.
If you drop a folder you get the folder name like:

```
[u'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Joaquin\\Desktop\\MyFolder']
```

or if you drop one or more files from a folder you get:

```
[u'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Joaquin\\Desktop\\MyFolder\\file_1.txt',
 u'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Joaquin\\Desktop\\MyFolder\\file_2.txt',
 ...................................................................
 u'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Joaquin\\Desktop\\MyFolder\\file_n.txt']
```

Is up to you how to handle these lists. For the example I suppose you are selecting files and I write the first one, `files[0]`, in the test control

Comment: So i have used the first chunk of code and kept it as a class, and the second chunk I have inserted into my current panel, the code between the dots, but can't seem to get it all to work.

Comment: Please, see edit. I forgot the notify method in the main class. This is called from the filedroptarget class and do whatever you want to do when dropping the file

Comment: Thanks joaquin, now when I drag and drop a folder I get TypeError: String or Unicode type required

Comment: Sorry, I copied the code from an application of mine that uses ListCtrl instead of a TextCtrl to read several files at the same time and I ajusted it only partially for the example here. Now the code does work when you drop one or more files as described.

Comment: That worked a treat. How to I change [u'/Library/Java'] into /Library/Java

Comment: What /Library/Java is ? A string ?, Then mylist[0]

Comment: Sorry, sorted, I used indir1 = '\n'.join(indir)

Comment: This works on MAC, but the drag and drop window doesn't show on Windows. Any ideas please?

Comment: Added .panel1 to the two line which needed it, fixed.

Comment: it is the right thing if you have the entry in a panel, which is the normal way on the other hand