# How to Open filename from wx txtctrl

Tags: user-interface, drag-and-drop, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a code that opens up a word document and inserts photos into it and stuff. The GUI part is proving to be very tricky. I would like it so that you can just drag and drop the documents, and then hit ok and the code I have working will run and use the filenames gotten from the drag and drop feature...

I have used the code from this thread:

[Wxpython browse for or drag and drop folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21747403/wxpython-browse-for-or-drag-and-drop-folder)

this part in particular:

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent,id):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'report maker', size=(300,200))
    dt1 = MyFileDropTarget(self)
    self.tc_files = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY)
    self.tc_files.SetDropTarget(dt1)


def notify(self, files):
    """Update file in testcontrol after drag and drop"""
    self.tc_files.SetValue(files[0])
```

basically I've dragged and dropped a word doc(using win32) and want to open it from another place in the program. I'm not sure how to open the file that is dragged and dropped. I've tried a lot of things sort of along this line...

```
    doc = word.Documents.Open(notify(tc_files, files[0])
```

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

After the drop, you should have saved the filename(s) or be able to get them from the widget you dropped them onto. Most wxPython widgets have a getter (like GetValue, GetSelection) that you can call to get the item or items from a widget. Just use that and pass that information on to the other part of your code that you're using to open the document with.